# In what ways can we distinguish between a human and bot behavior?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, game-theory, computer-vs-human

**Updated based on comments:**

In what ways can we distinguish a human being doing certain activities online and a bot programmed to do similar activities, say checking email, downloading some music files, shopping on ebay, searching on Google etc., or maybe trying to deface/hack a website, brute force a log-in password etc.

To limit the scope of the question and make it more clear, let us restrict our observations *only* to network-oriented behavior, some examples being- the amount of time spent doing XYZ thing online, the amount/type of data downloaded (say) from a file sharing website, the number of friends/followers on Social media websites, etc.

I guess it should possible to obtain some 'patterns' which will distinguish human behavior and programmed behavior.

The Turing test is not what I am looking for.

What techniques can be useful here? Machine learning? Game theory?

References to relevant academic/research articles will also be good.

Comment: See the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test).  See also Ken Regan's project about [detecting cheating in chess](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/thirteen-sigma/).

Comment: A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: I built https://bitpeople.org as ultimate solution to that problem. Uses Turing test (humans testing for bot or human. ) Edit: you seem to be asking about computers distinguishing humans from bots autonomously. In my opinion that will always be limited, but if perfection is not goal then it works.

Answer (score 10):

The most common/obvious way is a challenge-response test that is easy for humans but hard for computers (of course, but not only, [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)).

This kind of test is very effective{1} but falls under the HIP (Human Interactive Proofs) area: it's not transparent.

Typical, "simple" approaches to distinguish human website traffic from Bot are:

- time it takes to populate all the fields and click the submit button of an input form (frequently used but simple to bypass).

  Watching the cadence / pace of the communication is a more secure alternative (this is one of the feature of Google's [No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo));
- [honeypots](https://www.smartfile.com/blog/captchas-dont-work-how-to-trick-spam-bots-with-a-smarter-honey-pot/) (i.e. traps for bots that consist of a link or field present on the page that isn't visible to the human eye)
- analysis of *maximal continuous session length* (humans have to rest) and *correlation with time of day* (see [Distinguishing Humans from Bots
  in Web Search Logs](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Efeit/papers/Robo10TR.pdf))

It must be considered that [bot characteristics exhibit a wide variability for different crawler / different sites](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1016/j.comcom.2005.01.003), therefore it's difficult to derive simple, deterministic heuristics: rule based systems imply a long list of static rules that are difficult to define and maintain (even by experts).

Machine learning techniques are often used:

- [Web robot detection: A probabilistic reasoning approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220445627_Web_robot_detection_A_probabilistic_reasoning_approach) constructs a **Bayesian Network** that classifies automatically log sessions as being crawler or human induced
- [Discovery of web robot sessions based on their navigational patterns](https://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Eptan/papers/DMKD.pdf)
  uses **C4.5 decision tree algorithm** (after deriving the session features)
- [Detecting Click Fraud in Pay-Per-Click Streams of Online Advertising Networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/85d5/80b14e0464465059d47cf78c2dc4343c857b.pdf) develops **Bloom Filter**-derived [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).
- [Neural networks applied to speed cheating detection in online computer games](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4667339) adopts an **artificial neural network** for bot detection in [MMORPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game)s
- [Using Sentiment to Detect Bots on Twitter: Are Humans more Opinionated than Bots?](http://jpdickerson.com/pubs/dickerson14using.pdf) tries Gaussian naive Bayes, **Support Vector Machines** and  **Random Forests**

Almost [every available AI/ML "tool" has been experimented](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259695575_Comparison_of_Classification_Algorithms_to_tell_Bots_and_Humans_Apart). The main problem using these supervised machine learning tools is labeling the training dataset.

Even restricting the analysis to network-oriented behavior, this is a question of tremendous scope, for this reason I'm giving some keywords for further searches.

---

**Notes**

1. Machine Learning based attacks are improving and CAPTCHAs also serves as a benchmark task for artificial intelligence technologies (e.g. [The End is Nigh: Generic Solving of Text-based CAPTCHAs](https://cdn.elie.net/publications/the-end-is-nigh-generic-solving-of-text-based-captchas.pdf))

---

**Keywords**

HIP (Human Interactive Proofs), CAPTCHA, Keystroke dynamics, Keystroke cadence, typing dynamics, IDS (Intrusion Detection System), honeypot, click fraud, spambot

---

**References**

- [Designing Human Friendly Human Interaction Proofs (HIPs)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/designing-human-friendly-human-interaction-proofs-hips/) by Kumar Chellapilla, Kevin Larson, Patrice Simard, Mary Czerwinski (Microsoft Research)
- [The End is Nigh: Generic Solving of Text-based CAPTCHAs](https://cdn.elie.net/publications/the-end-is-nigh-generic-solving-of-text-based-captchas.pdf) by Elie Bursztein, Jonathan Aigrain, Angelika Moscicki, John C.Mitchell (2014)
- [Keystroke Dynamics User Authentication Based on Gaussian Mixture Model and Deep Belief Nets](https://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2013/565183) by Yunbin Deng, Yu Zhong (2013)
- [User Authentication Through Typing Biometrics Features](http://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Eptan/papers/DMKD.pdf) by Lívia C. F. Araújo, Luiz H. R. Sucupira Jr., Miguel G. Lizárraga, Lee L. Ling, andJoão B. T. Yabu-Uti (2005)
- [Distinguishing Humans from Bots in Web Search Logs](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Efeit/papers/Robo10TR.pdf) by Omer M. Duskin Dror, G. Feitelson
- [Web robot detection: A probabilistic reasoning approach](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220445627_Web_robot_detection_A_probabilistic_reasoning_approach) by Athena Stassopouloua, Marios D. Dikaiakos (2008)
- [An investigation of WWW crawler behavior: characterization and metrics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1016/j.comcom.2005.01.003) by M.D. Dikaiakos, A. Stassopoulou, L. Papageorgiou (Computer Communications, 2005)
- [Discovery of web robot sessions based on their navigational patterns](http://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Eptan/papers/DMKD.pdf) by Pang-Ning Tan, Vipin Kumar (2002)
- [Telling humans and computers apart automatically](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emblum/research/pdf/tell.pdf) by Luis von Ahn, Manuel Blum, John Langford (Comm. ACM, 2004)
- [Detecting Click Fraud in Pay-Per-Click Streams of Online Advertising Networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/85d5/80b14e0464465059d47cf78c2dc4343c857b.pdf) by Linfeng Zhang, Young Guan (IEEE, 2008)
- [Bots Problem in Online Games](https://www.ijsce.org/portfolio-item/c2307074314/) by Dewanshu Jain, Alok Gupta
- [Neural networks applied to speed cheating detection in online computer games](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4667339) by Gaspareto, Barone, Schneider (2008)
- [Quantifying Online Advertising Fraud: Ad-Click Bots vs Humans](https://docs.house.gov/meetings/IF/IF17/20180614/108413/HHRG-115-IF17-20180614-SD008.pdf) by Adrian Neal, Sander Kouwenhoven (2015). Other insights: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9023939
- [Comparison of Classification Algorithms to tell Bots and Humans Apart](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259695575_Comparison_of_Classification_Algorithms_to_tell_Bots_and_Humans_Apart) by Christian Hadiwijaya Saputra, Erwin Adi, Shintia Revina, Bina Nusantara (2014)
- [Using Sentiment to Detect Bots on Twitter: Are Humans more Opinionated than Bots?](http://jpdickerson.com/pubs/dickerson14using.pdf) by John P. Dickerson, Vadim Kagan, V.S. Subrahmanian (2014)